# how to display the model validation written in arabic in the view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am developing website for only Arabic language doesn't need English in that 
I downloaded the bootsrap-rtl it worked fine but I have a problem with model validation the error messages and display names which i wrote in model not appearing in Arabic but it appear as garbage values , what shall i do to get rid of that and display them in Arabic, am using mvc 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Resourse file(Resx) file. after that you have to mentioned Resource key and Resource type in Model. For more info you can follow below link.

http://www.codedigest.com/posts/29/using-resource-file-for-dataannotations-display-attribute-with-multi-language-support-in-aspnet-mvc